# Swagger UI not loading in Vert.X with Java

Tags: java, swagger, swagger-ui, vert.x

I have copied all files from https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/tree/master/dist in my resources/webroot folder. When I try to open Swagger UI on chrome I get these 3 errors with blank white screen. Also static handler is created to point at this folder.

```
router.route("/doc/*").handler(StaticHandler.create().setCachingEnabled(false).setWebRoot("webroot"));
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you look into the `*-bundle.js`-files in browser, you will see that at the `262464` line there are some invalid characters.
This is a consequence of the encoding problem on your machine. I.e. the `StaticHandler` delivers the resources with header `Content-Type` of e.g. `text/html;charset=Windows1251` instead of `UTF-8`.

To fix this problem I added a system property into my Gradle config:

```
plugins {
  id 'application'
}

applicationDefaultJvmArgs = [ 
  '-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8',
]
```

Other options of setting file encoding are [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/361975/setting-the-default-java-character-encoding)